# Validate multiple emails separated by semicolons and all must match a specific domain

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, email-validation

I want to validate this text field `email` which contains Multiple emails; all separated by semi colons but this isn't working. It should break when msn.com have been entered along with other emails.

```
var isMsn = ["msn.com"];
function myFunction() {
    var str = email.value;
    //var isMsn = str.includes("msn.com");
    var res = str.split(";");
    var isValid = false;
    //alert(res.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
        //alert(res[i]);
        var x = res[i];
        //check to see if this is an valid emAIL then
        var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if(x.match(mailformat)){
           alert("valid email address!");
           //IF isMsn = TRUE then check to see if is contains msn.com
           if (x.contains(isMsn) ){
               alert("it is MSN");
               //res[+1];
               isValid = true;   
           } 
           else {
               alert('no MSN');
               if (res.includes(isMsn)){
                   //alert('Cannot mix MSN emails with other');
                   //isValid = false;
                   //res[-1];
                   break;
               }
               //else{
               //alert('it is other');
               //isValid = true;
               //}
           }  
       }
       else{
           alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
           isValid = false;
       } 
   }    
}
```

I want it to loop through and all the emails must either match a msn.com or other NOT Both. for example, user@msn.com;user1@msn.com or user@hotmail.com;user1@hotmail.com but NOT user@msn.com;user1@hotmail.com

Not sure if .includes is the best option or not!

Comment: I'm assuming that your code is not working. Please edit your question and explain what is not working. Also, consider creating a working version in JSfiddle so we can see what the problem is live.

Comment: itsn't working, ideally when other emails have been entered along with msn.com; it should break, but doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

1) You should use `includes` instead of `contains`;
2) The `includes` or `contains` method accepts a string, not an array, so it should be `res.includes(isMsn[0])`;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

And if you want to validate by multiple domains - you should not name it `isMsn`, but `prohibitedDomains` and then to `Array.some` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) over this array.

```
prohibitedDomains.some((domain) => res.includes(domain))
```

Comment: but I want every email to be validated and must be either user@msn.com;user1@msn.com or user@hotmail.com;user1@hotmail.com not user@msn.com;user1@hotmail.com